# JavaScript redirect in web context of HTML & JS store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm having an issue with an which sits behind an enterprise authentication system. The app is an HTML5 web app which is loaded remotely through an iframe. This works fine, until the authentication system is integrated; this uses a javascript redirect which WinJS refuses to follow and logs an error APPHOST9624.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: sounds like [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Yes, I guessed it was something like this. However, I can't find any documentation which says that cross domain JS redirects are not allowed in a WinJS though that seems to be the case. These are not an issue when using the browser

Comment: To verify, this is only at the redirect phase? Docs for that code specify: APPHOST9624: "The app can’t use script to load the url url because the url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch another app." Apps can't launch other apps directly. Other apps can be launched by the user when the app implements certain contracts. For more info, see App contracts and extensions.